# Wordpress Navigation - Active Styling (CSS)

Tags: html, css

The website I'm working on is available at [ryanbenson.info/wordpress/](http://ryanbenson.info/wordpress/)

I converted my theme into a WordPress theme, and I'm not quite sure how to make my navigation work the same way.

On the previous version, located at ryanbenson.info, the individual pages call for different CSS documents, fading the navigation.

** note that the navigation is images, the top one fading as you hover

Now that the CSS and the header documents are standard for the whole site, I don't know how to go about styling it.

Comment: You'll have to narrow down your question to specifics to get a useful answer

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to assign specific CSS styles to different pieces of my navigation, depending on what page I am.

Comment: Say that I'm on the home page, I want to style the home button to match the hover style. Same with each other page individually.

Comment: I was curious if the menu was possible with css only. And it worked :) http://jsfiddle.net/yL6CJ/

Comment: Wow! I'll look at that today! It seems a bit much, but it sure is cool that you could figure it out! Thank you, good job!

Comment: You're welcome. I was a little bit bored :) The css is less than 50 lines. It seems a little messy due to the embedded fonts at the top of the css. The font is only 3kb. I tested it in chrome, ff and ie9. The css works as is with the markup of the wp_nav menu that is commented out in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somewhat depends on how you're doing things, but a general solution is:

1. Check the current URL.
2. If the link is to that URL, apply a class that makes it faded.

It looks like this menu is baked into your header rather than using any of WordPress's menu functions. So if your code looks something like this:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about">About</a>
<a href="/work">Work</a>
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

You'd instead have something like:

```
<a <?= is_home() ? 'class="current_page"' : '' ?> href="/">Home</a>
<a <?= is_page('about') ? 'class="current_page"' : '' ?> href="/about">About</a>
<a <?= is_page('work') ? 'class="current_page"' : '' ?> href="/work">Work</a>
<a <?= is_page('contact') ? 'class="current_page"' : '' ?> href="/contact">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Please consider the fact that everything is split up into parts when coding for WordPress

Comment: @RyanBenson: Yes, but those parts are rendered dynamically upon request. Just because your header is in header.php doesn't mean you can't tell what page you're on.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you meant then. If you would, please put things in terms of Wordpress.

Comment: @RyanBenson: OK, I added a WP-specific example.

Comment: @RyanBenson: I'm not sure how you see this as conflicting with the use of a symbol font. This is just about adding a class to the nav menu item that reflects the current page so you can style it differently. What you put in the nav item and what styles you apply are totally up to you.

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing. What you said makes sense, and I will use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to integrate the [nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) function into your theme.

First you have to register the menu in your functions.php

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Then you have to replace your current menu in the header.php with this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Then go to wp-admin -> Appearance -> Menus and add your menu.
Now you have a working menu with classes for the current menu item. You can now style your new menu like it was before and have the current menu item highlighted. I would suggest you use css-sprites or even better an icon font instead of the pictures.

Comment: I understand Wordpress menu systems, my problem is that I don't know how to bring a Wordpress menu together with a font icon system

Comment: Specifically, the style for the menu item representing the current page is `current-menu-item`.